# Why is fold defined using multiple parameter lists?

Tags: scala, fold

I'm trying to figure out the rhyme or reason to where parenthesis are used in Scala, in particular with the fold method:

```
val sum = prices.fold(0.0)(_ + _)
```

Why is it like that? Scala doesn't seem to follow the FP format in general (no parenthesis on method calls), but there it does... except it also requires parenthesis among the single-term accumulator? Why isn't either

```
val sum = prices.fold((0.0), (_ + _))
```

or

```
val sum = prices.fold 0.0 (_ + _)
```

?

Comment: Scala allows multiple parameter lists.

Comment: Paranthesis around function calls is not the FP standard. If I understand what you are referring to correctly, it comes from LISP/Scheme and from the fact that pretty much everything in those languages are s-expressions.  Fold is implemented like that (in pretty much any language) because it is a catamorphism on List. Thus seperating the lambda and the fixed point. (More detailed answer to follow when I am not on a packed train).

Comment: P.S. it's just that historically they have been represented that way. The real answer would be someone decided on that back in the day. It could have been the last synthax you posted or the second (tho I find this one confusing)

Comment: @sinanspd I mean the FP standard is not to have parenthesis, and Scala doesn't seem to follow that in general. It seems to be the "Multiple argument lists" thing mentioned by Jasper-m, but I'm not yet clear why those exist or are used here

Comment: Gotcha my bad. What Jasper mentioned is briefly covered here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html  "All the arguments in a given argument list contribute to inferring the type parameters simultaneously. The conclusions are then used as a premise when interpreting the next argument list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IterableOnce.fold`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1d75dae72cfad4e7fb5e821d81e8a29306623a5e/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L230) is defined using **multiple parameter lists** perhaps due to type inference reasons as suggested by Jörg W Mittag

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

on the other hand, for example, [`Either.fold`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1d75dae72cfad4e7fb5e821d81e8a29306623a5e/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L188) is defined using a single parameter list

```
def fold[C](fa: A => C, fb: B => C): C
```

Confirming type inference reasons, consider the following example

```
def zar[T](x: T)(f: (T, T) => T) = f(x, x)
def tar[T](x: T, f: (T, T) => T) = f(x, x)

zar(21)(_ + _)        // OK
tar(21, _ + _)        // Error: missing parameter type for expanded function 
tar[Int](21, _ + _)   // OK
```

Note how we had to explicitly specify type parameter to `tar` when not using multiple parameter lists.

Comment: Practically, type inference only flows between parameter lists, not within, which means that oftentimes you would have to provide an explicit type annotation.